# Why is there no Request.Path available in a .Net Core 3.0 ViewComponent

Tags: asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-viewcomponent, razor-class-library

In this ViewComponent I am Injecting IHttpContextAccessor, yet while the session property is present, ctx.HttpContext.Request.Path yields an empty string. Does anyone know why?

```
public class TopNavViewComponent : ViewComponent {

        private  IHttpContextAccessor _ctx;

        public TopNavViewComponent(IHttpContextAccessor ctx) {
            _ctx = ctx;
        }

        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(AdminVisit m_visit, bool IsTop) {
            NavObj navs = NavHelper.GetNav(_ctx.HttpContext.Request.Path, m_visit);
            navs.Path = _ctx.HttpContext.Request.Path;
            navs.IsTop = IsTop;
            navs.Path += _ctx.HttpContext.Session.Id;
            return View(navs);
        }
    }
```

btw I did not forget this in ConfigureServices

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

The ViewComponent is in a Razor Class Library - the code works apart from the missing Request.Path value.

I also have no Request.Path value in a Razor PageModel class in the same library:

```
 public class AuthPageModel : PageModel {

        [ViewData]
        public AdminVisit Visit { get; }
        [ViewData]
        public string ReqPath { get; }

        public AuthPageModel(IDBResolverService dbresolver, IHttpContextAccessor ctx) {
            Visit = new AdminVisit();

            ReqPath = "Are you here? " + ctx.HttpContext.Request.Path;

            if (ctx.HttpContext.User != null) {
```

The ctx.HttpContext.User is fine, but again, no Request.Path.
It is really baffling

Comment: Does the `AuthPageModel ` in a core 2.2 razor class library?Could you share steps to reproduce you problem?

Comment: Both the Razor class library and consuming website are .Net Core 3.0

Comment: @XingZou there are no steps, per se, its just that the Request.Path property is empty in the ViewComponent and Razor pages that i want to use it. The RouteValues (RouteValueDictionary) property is not null, and i am going to have to use that instead it seems